# Height issue with CSS Accordion FAQ

Tags: css, menu, height, accordion

I'm using this [a link](http://codepen.io/anzjoy/pen/bahAv) accordion menu to create a FAQ. Problem is that height is fixed, so whenever text is too long (or on mobile devices), text is cut us.

I've tried to use height: auto, overflow: hidden; min-height, !important and all the tags to make the height responsive, but whenever I do this, If I click on the tabs, the scrolling accordion effect doesn't work or it jumps to top page.

How can I solve this? I'd prefer not using JS or Jquery...thanks!

Here's the css

```
  .ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small {
height: 140px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is Setting `height:auto` for the below property.

```
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small {
    height: auto;
}
```

which is the one deciding height of the according body.

Plese find the [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJMLEY) for the updated code.

Comment: It works but it still has the issue I've explainer: it jumps and the "slowing movement" doesn't work anymore...I don't want it to look so broken :c

Answer (score 0):

The solution you use is CSS only. 
A CSS3 animation needs a defined height value to generate the transition – that's why the solution you used offers 3 different predefined heights.

Another approach would be to use the [max-height-trick which works for linear animations only though](http://www.thenerdary.net/post/20924702599/transitioning-max-height#comment-498618550).

The most common solution would be to toggle the animation via jQuery's slidetoggle().